# Inner matrix dimensions must agree error

Tags: matlab

I have a piece of code in which i save array values to a .txt file and then in another function i have to retrieve those values from .txt to an array...the code looks somewhat like this...

```
fid = fopen('c:\\coeffs2.txt','wt'); 
fprintf(fid,'%f\n',descr2);
fclose(fid);
```

And in another file i retrieve it this way..

```
fid = fopen('c:\\coeffs2.txt'); 
des2= [];
des2 = fscanf(fid,'%f\n'); 
fclose(fid);
```

i get the error as inner matrix dimension must agree...please help!

Comment: That means the two matrixes have different dimensions. Debug your code and figure out why they differ.

Comment: Just run it with `dbstop if error` and figure out where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure these lines are the ones generating that error? Exactly what is the line where the error occurs? Normally this would happen if you did (for example) a matrix multiplication (`*`) when you intended to do element-by-element multiplication (`.*`) with a non square matrix...

You can use `save('c:\\coeffs2.mat', 'descr2');` and `load('c:\\coeffs2.mat');` as an alternative (and more efficient) way to store / retrieve the matrix, and be sure you didn't change the dimensions.

Did you try to see what `size(descr2)` gives before the save, and after retrieving? Maybe you just need a `resize`...

Comment: So - what is the size of the matrix you read back in, compared to the one you saved?

Comment: when i try using save...i get an error ??? Error using ==> save
Argument must contain a string.

Comment: the size remains same 550x128

Comment: And what is the size of the other matrix? The `save` function takes two string arguments: the file name and the name of the variable you wish to save (not the variable itself).

Comment: Updated my answer to deal with the error you saw. If the size of the array is the same before and after the save, perhaps your problem lies somewhere else! When you leave the whole save/load thing out, does your code then work?

Comment: @aushima: Please do accept the above answer if it resolved your problem. This marks the question as solved and may possibly benefit the community.

Comment: @RoneyMichael - thanks for reminding Aushima of SO _mores_. And Aushima - glad it worked for you!